# Are the Azure DevOps extension for Slack affected by changing the slack workspace url?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, slack, azure-devops-extensions, azure-repos

In the company, we will change the slack workspace URL from https://**oldname**.slack.com to https://**newname**.slack.com. We have a lot of connections from Azure DevOps online service to Slack using two approaches. Older links via [service hooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/services/slack?view=azure-devops) in Azure Devops, new links are via slack applications [Azure Repos](https://adler-it.slack.com/apps/AKPEA4W4Q-azure-repos) and [Azure Pipelines](https://adler-it.slack.com/apps/AFH4Y66N9-azure-pipelines).

Thanks to Slack support, I know that Slack hooks are not affected if they were created after 2015. Which is the way Azure Devops uses for Service Hooks to Slack.

But I don't know if the Azure Repos and Azure Pipelines configurations will not be affected. E.g. Azure Repos is set up in Slack via `/azrepos subscribe [dev.azure.com/projecturl]` and this step automatically set the address to `azdevchatops.azure.com` in Azure Devops Service hooks settings. If Azure Repos is working somewhere with a Slack workspace URL, so I need to set up Azure Repos and Azure Pipelines in Slack again after changing the slack workspace url, that's what I don't know and what I'm asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do I need to reconfigure the Slack Apps for Azure Repos/Pipelines after changing the Azure DevOps workspace url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64928460/do-i-need-to-reconfigure-the-slack-apps-for-azure-repos-pipelines-after-changing)

Comment: Please close one of the question you made. It looks like you did double click :)

Comment: No, we need to make change on both side (change url on Slack and Azure DevOps). One question is about changes to made when we change slack url, one question is about changes to made when Azure DevOps url will change. Theare are different scopes. These URL changes will happen in different times, so questions are different and answers will be too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We do not need to reconfigure notification in the slack workspace.

As test result, I create notifications via `/azpipelines  subscribe [dev.azure.com/projecturl]`  to check the pipeline status, I can successfully receive the notification in the slack.

Then I changed the workspace name and workspace URL to the new ones, and re-run the pipeline. I can still receive notifications, you could check the pic below.

[image]

Comment: I just tested and you're right. All notification methods work, classic incoming web pages, Azure Repos notifications and Azure Pipelines notifications. Great finding.

Comment: I tested a scenario where after changing the Slack workspace url, I created another slack workspace with the original name to remove the redirect from the original workspace to the new one. Notifications continue to work, ie. everything works as it should, even if redirect is canceled. That's great news.