# Are the Azure DevOps extensions for Slack affected by changing the Azure DevOps url?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, slack, azure-devops-extensions, azure-repos

At the company, we will change the URL for the Azure Devops workspace from `https://oldname.visualstudio.com` to `https://dev.azure.com/newname`. We have a lot of connections to Slack in Azure DevOps using two approaches. Older links via [service hooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/services/slack?view=azure-devops) in Azure Devops, new links are via slack applications [Azure Repos](https://adler-it.slack.com/apps/AKPEA4W4Q-azure-repos) and [Azure Pipelines](https://adler-it.slack.com/apps/AFH4Y66N9-azure-pipelines).

Service hooks in Azure DevOps use Slack's Incoming webhooks, so they will not be affected. However, Microsoft prefers to use its Slack Azure Repos and Azure Pipelines extensions, and the way they work is not clear. E.g. Azure Repos is set up in Slack via `/azrepos subscribe [https://oldname.visualstudio.com/projecturl]` and this step automatically set the address to `azdevchatops.azure.com` in Azure Devops Service hooks settings.

So it looks like you need to reconfigure all subscriptions in Azure Repos and Azure Pipelines after changing the Azure DevOps URL. But that is a presumption. It is not mentioned in the documentation and that is why I ask. We have enough connections and that means a lot of manual work to configure everything in Slack via `/azrepos subscriptions` and `/azpipelines subscriptions` again.
Does anyone have the experience that when using Azure Repos and Azure Pipelines as Slack Apps, everything has to be reconfigured in Slack as soon as the Azure DevOps workspace address changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notification integration is seamless. Notifications work when you change the name (and URL) of Azure DevOps organisation.

I tested just now and everything is ok.

Note: there are another problem. After Azure Devops organisation URL change you need to reinstall/register build agents again to the new URL. If you use hosted Azure Pipelines in cloud, you need in `Project Settings > Agent Pools > Azure Pipelines > Agents` disable `Hosted Agent` and enabled again [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLB8q.png). Otherwise, CI / CD pipelines do not work.